# Cant use boolean

Tags: modeling, modifiers, customization, selection-tools

I just started playing around with Blender, and been trying to model a monitor stand in the shape of a drawer, but no matter what I search or try to follow a tut I cant do a boolean mod on my project.

I've started from scratch about 4 times now, every time with the same result. Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Your screenshot only shows a bunch of objects and none of them have any modifiers added to them, so no _Boolean_ modifier. There is absolutely nothing visible there indicating that you tried using a _Boolean_ modifier or where it failed. Simply saying no tutorial can make it work does not provide any specific information what you actually did to make it work.